# How to add image to PDF file in Python?

Tags: python, pdf

I have a PDF document but I must put my own image on it. It's an official document and I must apply an image with the text "example" to the whole page.

Is there any way to solve this problem in python?

(text in the document is curves)

Comment: I encountered a similar problem about a month ago but couldn't easily find a solution in Python. Writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look into [pypdf](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/). You might use something like the following code to apply an overlay:

```
page = PdfReader("document.pdf").pages[0]
overlay = PdfReader("overlay.pdf").pages[0]
page.merge_page(overlay)
```

Put any overlay you want, including "Example", into `overlay.pdf`.
Personally, I prefer PDFTK, which, while not strictly Python, can be invoked from a script with `os.system(command)`.

Answer (score 12):

If you're here from Google, [pypdf > 3.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/) is the latest project. [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/#history) / [PyPDF3](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF3/#history) / [PyPDF4](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF4/#history) are no longer maintained as you can see in their latest release date. The syntax has changed somewhat.

```python
import pypdf

# overlay.pdf contains the image
with open("original.pdf", "rb") as inFile, open("overlay.pdf", "rb") as overlay:
    original = pypdf.PdfReader(inFile)
    background = original.pages[0]
    foreground = pypdf.PdfReader(overlay).pages[0]
    
    # merge the first two pages
    background.merge_page(foreground)
    
    # add all pages to a writer
    writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()
    for page in original.pages:
        writer.add_page(page)
    
    # write everything in the writer to a file
    with open("modified.pdf", "wb") as outFile:
        writer.write(outFile)
```

Comment: I'm the maintainer of pypdf and PyPDF2 now. The latest project is `pypdf`. I've deprecated PyPDF2 in favor of pypdf. PyPDF3 and PyPDF4 are far behind and don't have any development in the past years.

Comment: Is there any way to alter the translation and size of the overlaying pdf? I want to insert a single image at a specific position instead of overlaying the whole page.