# Printing a logo and boilerplate text to a PDF document using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently using `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf` to build a PDF report consisting of several matplotlib plots.  Currently, there are 9 pages of plots.  Each page consists of about 7 subplots (I'm using `plt.subplot2grid`).

Is there a way for me to do the following?

a) print a logo to the first page of the PDF document and then have the 9 pages of plots appears on pages 2 through 10

b) print a disclaimer and some other boilerplate language underneath the logo

Thanks!

Comment: I searched StackOverflow for a solution.  The solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276409/how-to-add-image-to-pdf-file-in-python seems promising, but I was not able to get it to work.  The ideal solution for me would allow me to add a logo and some boilerplate text.  If I'm only able to create some text, then that would work, too!

Comment: Are you limited to only use `matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf`? If not, I recommend you use `reportlab`.