# How to add a signature into a specific field in a PDF document using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, pdfrw

I tried adding an image into a PDF in a specific field in a particular position,
I also referred to another post in the community ([How to add image to PDF file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276409/how-to-add-image-to-pdf-file-in-python/24768512?newreg=a594a6f9dd3e41e999291aa15bcb3e92)),
This code allows us to overlay the entire Image over PDF, but we want to insert the image in a particular position of a PDF.

Thanks in advance for the Leads.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PyMuPDF package for e.g. if you want to add a signature image file at a specific position where there is Text "Approved By" in the pdf say at the last page of the pdf, you could do it like this:-
First install the pymupdf package in your system at the Anaconda terminal.

```
(base) C:\Users\User>pip install pymupdf
```

Then in your favourite code editor, import the package as follows_

```
import fitz #pymupdf

pdfPath = <pathtoinputPdf>
signaturePath = <pathtosignatureImage>
outputPath = <pathtooutputPdf>

pdf_doc = fitz.open(pdfPath)
last_page = pdf_doc[-1]#extract last page contents

checked_by_text = "Approved By"
text_instances = last_page.search_for(checked_by_text)
#if the text is found, insert the image there
if text_instances:
    x, y,x2,y2 = text_instances[0]
    #above gives the coordinates in pixels of the bounding box of the text 
    #from Left Top to Right Bottom. To insert image above the text, we
    #create new left top and right Bottom pixel values as follows.
    y -= 5
    y2-=50
    # Insert signature image at (x,y2) Left Top to (x2,y) Bottom Right
    rect = fitz.Rect(x, y2,x2, y)
    img = open(signaturePath, "rb").read()
    last_page.insert_image(rect,stream = img )
    
    #save final pdf
    pdf_doc.save(outputPath)
else:
print("Text 'Approved By' not found in the PDF")
```